# Creating a custom .tpl file for a view in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I am creating a view in Drupal which will have a list of Books. Each Book is a caontent with fields like Book Title, Authors and Book Image. I have created the view and set the display to GRID mode.

When I click on each book in the Grid, it will take me to the original content where all the fields related to Book will be displayed. The display will be in a default mode and I need to change the style of this display.

I tried creating a .tpl (template) file for this output but not able to configure how to bring in the fields of this views (title, author and book image). I wanted to have my own css for this display and would like to know how a custom .tpl file could be used for a view in Drupal.

Comment: it's not clear from the question if the landing page (the page with book details you reach following the view generated links) it's a simple "node page" or it's generated by a view itself. i think you just have to create a file called node-book.tpl.php (just copy the default node.tpl.php in you theme directory) assuming your custom content type it's called 'book'.

Comment: The view is actually a block in Drupal and placed in a page called 'Book'. I created the .tpl but I need to know how to display the details of the view in the .tpl. Also I need to have my own CSS for this view generated through .tpl file.

Comment: inside your node-book.tpl.php you have a variable $node you can use to print data for each field. install devel module then use dsm($node) inside the tpl to output these variables.